# Additional "1" value in dropdown sourced from MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

have a question about connecting Dropdown select option in HTML from MYSQL source. I have successfully connected my dropdown item with database, but I have noticed, that there is additional "1" value in dropdown, which is not stored in database. Here is how does dropdown look:
[image: Here is how does dropdown look:]

There are screenshots from database data and it's structure:
[image: Database's data]

[image]

And finally, there is PHP code, which connects my dropdown item with database:

```
  $sql = "SELECT dan, datum, lokacija FROM termini";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  echo "<td><select name='dan, datum, lokacija'>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['dan'], $row['datum'], $row['lokacija'] . "'>" . $row['dan'], print(" , "),  $row['datum'], print(" , "), $row['lokacija'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select></td>";

  ?>
</select>
```

Why are there "1" values before 'Datum' and 'Lokacija'?

Comment: your code accepts mysql injects use mysqli_ or pdo connection instead

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi I support your advice, but this code is not accepting any input parameter, so it's impossible to *inject* something here. Not all code written with the classic mysql_ extension is prone to injection. If so, PHP+MySQL would have been a major security issue for many years.

Comment: thanks Kaii  for telling me that i am not that much experienced but in SOF generally all questions using mysql_ has comment like this :).....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the additional "1"s in your output are the `print()` statements in this line:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['dan'], $row['datum'], $row['lokacija'] . "'>" 
     . $row['dan'], print(" , "),  $row['datum'], print(" , "), $row['lokacija'] 
     . "</option>";
```

And in fact, it doesn't matter if you are using the `,` or `.` syntax for echo here.

The reason lies in your `print(" , ")` statements:

- `print()` is executed before `echo`, because it is part of `echo`s parameter.
- `print(" , ")` is echoing the string `" , "` to STDOUT ***and*** is returning true (= 1) to signal success.
- the resulting `true` value is converted to `1` and then written to STDOUT by `echo`.

Using `echo` and `print()` in combination is basically saying the same thing twice over. Your code should just be:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['dan']. $row['datum']. $row['lokacija'] . "'>" 
     . $row['dan'] . " , " . $row['datum'] . " , " . $row['lokacija'] 
     . "</option>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code has issues.
`name='dan, datum, lokacija'` - name should be one value.why use commas
concatenation is wrong.(joining the vars)
`$row['dan'], $row['datum'], $row['lokacija']`   - incorrect
`$row['dan']." ".$row['datum']." ".$row['lokacija']` - correct

Comment: thank you very much! Now it works! I am really glad for your fast response! :)